# Jquery Elegant code 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's a better and more elegant way of writing this jquery code?

```
$('#email-prompt').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#email-prompt, #mask').fadeOut();
    $('.email-prompt').fadeOut().remove();
    $('.count').delay(500).fadeIn();
    $('.notice').delay(1000).fadeIn();

    $('.count.beta span').countTo({
        from: 0,
        to: 2281,
        speed: 1500,
        refreshInterval: 50
    });

    $('.count.alpha span').countTo({
        from: 0,
        to: 3227,
        speed: 1500,
        refreshInterval: 50
    });

    $('.count.charlie span').countTo({
        from: 0,
        to: 2134,
        speed: 1500,
        refreshInterval: 50
    });
});
```

Also, please share some tips and best practices on writing organized jquery code.

Thanks!

Comment: You may get better traction for this question over on CodeReview.

Comment: Yeah, see the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. " http://stackoverflow.com/faq